# Buidling my own bike - what are these VERY small rings for in the fork?

Tags: frames, fork

I am trying to build my own bike. I ordered a frame that came with a fork and the stem locks.

Now I am finished and i unfortunately see two of these VERY small rings.. they came with the fork+frame and fits on the fork.. but what are the for? and where should they actually go? banana for scale

[image]

Comment: Are you a member of the Things Found in Walls group? The banana for scale is great lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a headset spacer. If its internal diameter is about 1⅛ inch or 28.6 mm, then it comes on the top part of it.

It is hard to say where exactly without knowing a specific headset mounting instructions.

In a manual that I have for one of my headsets, there is a tiny 0.25 mm thick spacer that goes just under the bearing cover (See number 3 in the picture).

[image: 0.25 mm spacer]

Comment: That's definitely a headset spacer. Especially threaded headsets may benefit from these because if you cut your steerer tube for a threaded headset of certain stack height, and then later install a headset with a different stack height, the spacers could save your day. Why they come with a new frame+fork combination with uncut steerer is a mystery to me. Of course if the steerer was pre-cut for a certain assumed stack height, then it's understandable why the headset spacers were bundled.

Comment: @juhist these types of thinnest spacers are usually an integral part of the headset, and go under the conical "cap", closer to the rubber seals. They are not used to accommodate for steering tube's length — this spacer can be < 0.5mm thin, and it will play no difference at all in such a role